# Convert day of month to weekday format for table in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

for part of my program I need to read given values in the past week, group them by weekday  and then display them in a table in MVC. I have managed to display a long list of numerical days (showing repeats) with their matching data but I need the format to be from monday-sunday which means it would have to combine values that occur on the same day.

My controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index(string TimeState)
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime week = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
        string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        string email = (from x in db.Users where x.Id == userID select x.Email).FirstOrDefault();



        IEnumerable<ValuesList> valuesList = from x in db.UsageDatas
                                             where week  <= x.Time && x.Time <= today && x.UserEmail == email                                                 
                                             select new ValuesList
                                             {
                                                 Dates = x.Time.Day.ToString(),
                                                 Values = x.Delta ,
                                             };


        State state = new State
        {
            state = TimeState,
            valuesLists = valueList,                                  
            selectedDate = "0"
        };
        return View(state);
    }
```

View:

```
        <div class="Table Heading"><h3>Recent Water Usage</h3></div>
    @{


    }

    <table class="greyGridTable">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Value</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>

        @foreach (var item in Model.valuesLists)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dates)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Values)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

Model:

```
   public class State
{

    public string state { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ValuesList> valuesLists { get;set;}
    public string TimeState { get; set; }
    public string selectedDate { get; set; }

}

public class ValuesList
{
  public string Dates { get; set; }
public string Values { get; set; }


}
```

what the current table looks like:
note: its showing the current month day*
[image: Table]

My LINQ is pretty limited so any insight would be highly appreciated. 
here is the new error [image: The new error]

Comment: You'll need to do some grouping and some summing.

Comment: Sorry for the weird comment but if you need to group them by weekday why don't you try to group them by weekday?

Comment: When you group them by weekday, how do you want the Delta summarized?

Comment: MongZhu Ive tried but I dont know how to send to the IEnumerable in a weekday format. @NetMage just have the delta's added up for each day.

Comment: Doesn't seem like `Dates` and `Values` should be plural, then. Before the `select` put in `group x.Delta by x.Time.DayOfWeek into xg` and in the `select` put `Dates = xg.Key.ToString("ddd"), Values = xg.Sum()`

Comment: Next weird comment : we can only see what you have posted but not what you have tried ;-)

Comment: @NetMage its giving an error for the `Values = xg.Sum()`. "Days of week does not contain a definition for Sum".mong Zhu what ive tried is not worth looking at lol

Comment: You'd have to put in what you tried to get that error - it doesn't make sense if coded properly.

Comment: @NetMage I edited the original with the new error

Comment: There is a SelectMany missing I think

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice `Delta` was a string (I assume, you didn't say) and I assumed added up meant it was a number. How do you want Delta summarized again?

Comment: Yeah sorry my mistake, Delta is just added together when their dates are equal. If you look at the table picture there are multiple values that have date 25 for eg. it would be 310 +267

Answer (score 1):

You want to adding today's data?
If yes.

```
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
        DateTime week = today.AddDays(-7); // or -6  think about it
        string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        string email = (from x in db.Users where x.Id == userID select x.Email).FirstOrDefault();

        var valuesList = db.UsageDatas
            .Where(x => x.Time >= week && x.Time < tomorrow && x.UserEmail == email)
            //.AsEnumerable() //posible need it for execute sql before take DayOfWeek
            .GroupBy(x => x.Time.DayOfWeek)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                DayOfWeek = x.Key,
                Values = x.Select(m => m.Delta).Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b)
            })
            .OrderBy(m => m.DayOfWeek)
            .Select(x => new ValuesList
            {
                Dates = x.DayOfWeek.ToString(),
                Values = x.Values
            });
```

Group by DayOfWeek and aggregate Delta as you want

For sum of Deltas: (but it's crutch)

```
 Values = x.Select(x =>
            {
                int.TryParse(x, out var value);
                return value;
            })
            .Sum()
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to find out how to aggregate Delta now then we are all set to go :)

Comment: @JoshuaWeiss Replace `.Select...Aggregate` with `.Sum(m => m.Delta)`

Comment: yeah its a string, Ive tried converting both values to ints and then back into a string but I cant manage to do it.

Comment: add a parsing of deltas

Comment: ` int.TryParse(m, out var value);` m shows an error: Cannot convert ~model.Usage date to string. Im sorry for all the questions but this project is literally due in 3 hours and this is the last little bit that needs fixing. So im pretty desperate lol.

Comment: you try to parse date. please, show your new code. (just add in question)